# Powershell in Mac issue

Tags: azure, powershell, apple-m1, arm64

I installed Powershell in Mac ([Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos?view=powershell-7.3)) and I want to execute the below Powershell commands

```
Connect-AzureAD
Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $AppObjectId -RefObjectId  $SPObjectId
Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $AppObjectId
```

But I'm getting the below error.

> Connect-AzureAD: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Executed the below command also. But still the same error.

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

```
Import-Module AzureAD

Import-Module: The current processor architecture is: MSIL. The module '/Users/user_one/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureAD/2.0.2.140/AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
```

Comment: Did you `Import-Module AzureAD` too?

Comment: Yes Imported as well

Comment: Odd. Does any other AzureAD commands show up when you do `Get-Command -Module AzureAD`? (after running `Import-Module AzureAD` of course)

Comment: Sorry my bad. Import command failed. I have added the output to the question

Comment: I'm having M1 Chip MacBook

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because `AzureAD` PowerShell module is not supported on Mac. From the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0):

[image]

To work with Graph API on Mac using PowerShell, you can install `Microsoft.Graph` module. You can find more information about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview?view=graph-powershell-1.0.

Comment: The screenshot you've posted says that `PowerShellGet` is not supported outside Windows, it doesn't say anything about platform compatibility of the `AzureAD` module

Comment: I have tried it on Mac previously and faced the same problem as the post has mentioned. I believe it has something to with some security protocols only available on Windows.

Comment: I installed Microsoft.Graph module now. So what command should be executed instead of Connect-AzureAD

Comment: @Container-Man - Please the getting started guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0.